# release images from memory, swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, memory

i have created one app with 2 viewcontroller embed with navigation controller. the 1st view controller only consist of one button(to trigger seague to 2nd view controller) and 2nd view controller consist only one UIImageView with one high resolution image(300MB). When it is showing 2nd view controller the memory tooks around 300 MB and i return to 1st view controller (popviewcontroller) the memory usage still consume 300MB. After some research i guess the image loaded is still store in the cache and it is not released. So my question is how can i manually release the image so the memory usage can goes down?

EDITED
Hi all, answer to my own question.Use "autoreleasepool" would do the job.

Comment: How do you return your 1st view controller? Do you keep reference to 2nd view controller?

Comment: Make sure you're not holding a reference to that image in your first VC. Usually popping a VC clears it from memory.

Comment: i return to 1st view controller by pop current view controller(navigation controller). Nop, i didn't keer a reference

Comment: first view controller consist only one button. and not keeping a reference of 2nd view controller

Comment: Is the UIImageView in the second controller a weak IBOutlet?

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, it is

Comment: It happens with me too. If I go to that screen again and load image, No memory increase/decrease occurs. I would also like to know it's solution.

Comment: You can deallocate memory forcely 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827319/forcing-an-object-to-deallocate-under-arc

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani Do you mean by set the imageView = nil inside autoreleasepool loop? i have tried the memory does not goes down

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try with this way. If the size of the image is too big never put it in image xcassets folder. Place it in project navigator and use it as path.

```
            if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: image name in string, ofType: image format like "png" or "jpg"){
                if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path){
                    imageView.image = image
                }else{
                    print(" No image found")
                }
            }else{
                print("No image path found")
            }
```

if the size of  the image is big don't use like this way

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: image name)
```

According to apple documentation [App doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage). It doesn't release the use memory. It caches the image for the future use. Use the 
imageWithContentsOfFile:
 or 
init(contentsOfFile:)
 method to create an image object where the initial data is not in a bundle. These methods load the image data from disk each time, so you should not use them to load the same image repeatedly. 
And if you want to know details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6713862/3887987) is the answer.